# New laptop screen is misaligned

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I recently had the top half of my laptop replaced.

Unfortunately, the display on the new screen is misaligned. It's a few millimetres to the right and down so there's a small blank bit on the top and left and a small amount is off the edge of the screen. Far from unusable but enough to be extremely irritating. It may be my imagination but it may be getting worse.

I've tried restarting and reinstalling drivers.

Laptop is a HP Pavillion running Windows 10. The GPU is Intel HD Graphics and NVIDIA GForce GTX 1050. (I can supply other specs if necessary). As far as I can tell, neither has the opportunity to "move the screen a bit", which would be the ideal solution. As this is a laptop, I see no hardware option.

I'd like to fix this without taking it back to the store that did this if possible due to the time that would take. Is there an easy way to shift the screen?

Comment: What you're seeing is most likely the edge of the panel, I would assume it has been poorly fitted. Without taking the back off the screen and re-applying the panel, you won't resolve this.

Comment: I agree with Spikey_richie here. Best option is to go back to the store. A misaligned screen can damage more easily, you still have warranty.

Comment: If the alignment is off, and you think it is getting worse, then the display is probably not fastened correctly inside. I suggest taking the machine back to the store. The display is tricky to fit and fasten inside.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I opened the BIOS and the problem persists there. More evidence that this is a hardware issue?